# How can I recover a standard user's password using the admin password?

Tags: macos, terminal, security, password, keychain

I'm trying to recover a standard user's password on Mac. I'm using OSX Sierra. Using the admin, can I view this password? Either with Terminal or otherwise?

Comment: You can't view or get the password with a single command. Some brute-force pw cracking is required: [Password cracking](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/220863/93229)

Comment: An admin can *reset* another user's password, but cannot (except by brute-force guessing) view another user's password. User passwords are stored in hashed form, which means that it's not possible to directly recover the password from the stored hash.

Answer (score 1):

Nope is the general prognosis for this.

Assign them a new password if you don’t intend to crack / reverse engineer the password or hope to find it stored in a plan text file.

- https://github.com/octomagon/davegrohl

If you just need to get at the files and not crack to get at the user keychain, use the system preferences and an admin account to make a new password for the user account in question.