# Managed, Mobile account on Mac not giving me the option to change password when Admin is unlocked?

Tags: macos, password, administrator

I'm trying to change/access mobile and managed accounts on a Mac network system. System Preferences won't give me the option to change a password of a mobile account. How can I view or change this password?

Answer (score 2):

A managed / mobile account is controlled from the directory so you can't change that password unless there's some sort of integration with a tool like Apple Enterprise Connect or Nomad (https://nomad.menu) where the tool calls to the Active Directory to make the password change.

All Mac accounts have their password encrypted and obfuscated, so you'd have a hard time cracking them.

- [How can I recover a standard user's password using the admin password?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306354/)

Best bet is to get your admin staff to assist you in resetting the passwords or letting you be the administator of this Mac and set up local accounts.