# How to get a password hash through terminal in Recovery Mode?

Tags: macos, terminal, password, recovery

Is it possible to extract a user’s password hash through the terminal in Recovery Mode?

Comment: For what reason?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify a special macOS version but at least in Sierra it can be done by:

- open Terminal.app in the menubar > Utilities
- get the name of the main system volume with `diskutil list` (e.g. *Macintosh HD*)
- enter in Terminal:

  ```
  defaults read /Volumes/<volume_name>/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/<user_name>.plist ShadowHashData|tr -dc 0-9a-f|/Volumes/<volume_name>/usr/bin/xxd -r -p|/Volumes/<volume_name>/usr/bin/plutil -convert xml1 - -o -
  ```

  Example (with the main system volume name *Macintosh HD* and the user name *user272783*):

  ```
  defaults read /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/user272783.plist ShadowHashData|tr -dc 0-9a-f|/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/usr/bin/xxd -r -p|/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/usr/bin/plutil -convert xml1 - -o -
  ```

  If you specify a file name and choose a r/w volume as destination drive, you can write the file to a volume (`... -o /Volumes/FlashDrive/user272783.plist`)

---

Please check: [What type of hash are a Mac's password stored in?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220729/what-type-of-hash-are-a-macs-password-stored-in)