# Cracking hashes for MacOS passwords

Tags: macos, password

I've followed practically all the tutorials on cracking hashes for a macOS password, but I've come up empty handed.

I've ultimately come up with this hash:

`Admin:$ml$28169$d144a9af9619163e3a77170cb41e3f6e554b22f9683f3c3c8a05676a87b41056$8c6f600a6f3d73a3edd45e6010669da4ed68ba1291489b31dd744af96b12f39d07abe5fbeac0db3cf377e2531d66a2d6d4eb1e281be21b10dea21b6cf13c432c1cb7299c827b891d72c98f5df375b0947f6eb5b2b42e33b1a16212671b71f2671dbd108314335674cad1dee8f281b6221600920abba7a2512bf3493b4cebfd69`

I have tried both `hashcat -m 7100` and john the ripper, but still nothing.

Any help would be immensely appreciated. I am trying to crack a Yosemite password.

Comment: you may also get more answers if you provide a reason why you are doing this? Research? Locked out of your own laptop, curiosity, stolen laptop ;-)

Comment: @Deesbek personal research, may or may not be getting into mischief at school

Comment: LOL - ah the famous Harry Potter hack.

Comment: @Deesbek any further help or tips on the hash?

Comment: Try the NSA. I don't think anybody at this site is willing to help you break the law, or at a minimum, promote unethical behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You may find that just like with most unix like systems OS X uses a salt and a hash.

I would review some of the answers on AskDifferent such as:

[What type of hash are a Mac's password stored in?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/220729/10733)

> Your password and the salt is grilled by sha512 many times, then the
>   result is base64'ed and reverse xxd'ed. Together with the salt and the
>   iterations it's xxd'ed and base64'ed again.

Comment: so yes, i did follow that tutorial today and on the second to last step it says how to put together the hash for hash cat, which is the one I've included in my original post. so it's $ml$<iterations(integer)>$<salt(hex)>$<entropy(hex)>

Comment: well if they are using sha512, then I don't think it can be cracked

Comment: @scipsycho well i mean in the tutorial that Deesbek linked, the poster said it worked just fine....