# How to view local user password in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, security, password, user-account

I have the administrators password and account but I am interested in finding the password of a local user. I am not trying to reset the password but find out the exact password that was already set. I also encounter problems with finding the password in the terminal because if I ever do find a password,It is usually encrypted and does not work when copy-pasted onto the password box.

Comment: Why do you need the password? You say that you have admin access so you already can access all the files in the userprofile.

Answer (score 3):

The passwords are stored in a [salted hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)), so there is no way to just read them.
If you want to crack the password, [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220729/what-type-of-hash-are-a-macs-password-stored-in/220863) is a guide from a few years ago, it still works.

If you need access to the files in the User profile and you have admin access, you can just change the permissions in finder or using `chmod` in the terminal. [Here](https://www.macinstruct.com/node/415) is a guide on how to achieve that.